# How do I add the Windows GUI to Windows 2016 Server Core?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

We just got our dedicated server from Rackspace. It was loaded with W2008 on it. I decided to put the most recent OS on it so I wouldn't have to upgrade it later. Apparently during the installation, I selected the no gui option.

I tried to install the gui from powershell that I've seen reference on other website.

For example:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Server-GUI-Shell -Restart
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> Install-WindowsFeature Server-GUI-Shell -Restart
Install-WindowsFeature : ArgumentNotValid: The role, role service, or feature name is not valid: 'Server-GUI-Shell'.
The name was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature Server-GUI-Shell -Restart
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Server-GUI-Shell:String) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NameDoesNotExist,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
False   No             InvalidArgs    {}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get a gui installed on this server.

All references I've seen to installing the gui say to use the  Server-GUI-Shell.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's no longer possible to switch from Server Core to the full GUI or vice versa in Server 2016 - either through Server Manager, `PowerShell`, or `DISM`.  You must make the choice initially at install time.
From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started%2Fwindows-server-2016):

> Unlike some previous releases of Windows Server, you cannot convert
>   between Server Core and Server with Desktop Experience after
>   installation. For example, if you install Server Core and later decide
>   to user Server with Desktop Experience, you should do a fresh
>   installation (and vice versa).

A good community article on the topic: https://superwidgets.wordpress.com/2016/10/29/windows-server-2016-gui-options/

The capability to convert from one to the other via Server Manager and the Install/Remove-WindowsFeature cmdlets existed in Server 2012 and Server 2012 R2.

Comment: `existed in Server 2012 and Server 2012 R2` - It existed, but it didn't work at all reliably after you had applied security updates to the system.  You either needed to maintain a patched wim, or just re-install.

Comment: @Zoredache, that's mostly the case if you started with Server Core and then tried to convert up.  If you started with the Server with a GUI, converted down, then back up - it should work more smoothly.  Part of the design idea was that people would start with a GUI and use it to get their server configured the way they liked.  Then they could convert down, and do `Remove-WindowsFeature -Remove` to get rid of the SxS content.

Comment: Also mentioned on Microsoft site as well. [Source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2017/04/05/switching-between-windows-server-2016-server-core-and-desktop-experience/)
> `We prioritized consistency with the Windows client desktop over the
> ability to switch between Server Core and Server with Desktop.
> Replacing the legacy desktop in Server with the Windows 10 desktop
> experience resulted in our inability to support the Windows Server
> 2012 R2 behavior.`